# wijmo.xlsx & JSZip with Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, jszip, wijmo5

I am having troubles using `wijmo.xlsx` and `JSZip` on Angular 4 for my Wijmo project. `wijmo.xlsx` requires `JSZip` as a dependency.

When I import `JSZip` in a TypeScript file as below it displays error an for `JSZip`.

```typescript
import * as JSZip from 'jszip';
```

I installed `JSZip` using `npm install jszip --save` but it did not work.

I installed `@types/jszip` this time and error is gone. But when I am trying to use `JSZip` it is showing following errors:

```typescript
(index):55 (SystemJS) window.require is not a function
TypeError: window.require is not a function at Object.eval 
(http://localhost:5555/node_modules/wijmo/wijmo.xlsx.js:13:871)
at eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/wijmo/wijmo.xlsx.js:14:4)
at eval (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/wijmo/wijmo.xlsx.js:15:3)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at Object.eval 
(http://localhost:5555/node_modules/wijmo/wijmo.grid.xlsx.js:13:694) at eval 
(http://localhost:5555/node_modules/wijmo/wijmo.grid.xlsx.js:14:4) at eval 
(http://localhost:5555/node_modules/wijmo/wijmo.grid.xlsx.js:15:3) at eval 
(<anonymous>)
```

What is the correct procedure to install JSZip and use it with Angular 4? Do we need to install `@types/jszip` first and then `JSZip`?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add it as a module then see this link

https://www.grapecity.com/en/forums/wijmo/excelimportexport-in-angul

If you need to add it as a file then see this link

- [Wijmo ExcelImportExport in Angular 2 project 'window.require is not a function' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692045/wijmo-excelimportexport-in-angular-2-project-window-require-is-not-a-function)